# Show Button on Label MouseHover in WPF

Tags: wpf

In my application i have a `Startup Window` that contains (Tips, Information, etc.). A part of the window contains 3 `Labels` on the left side and 3 hidden `Buttons` on the right side. What i want is whenever a user hovers on one of the `Labels` the button which is located on the other side of the `Label` shows up.

I know how to show the `Button` if i hover over it using `Triggers`, but how to show the button when i hover the `Label`.

Is it possible for such thing to be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that easily using a `DataTrigger` and the `Binding.ElementName` property. This simple example shows how:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Click me">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, 
                        ElementName=SomeLabel}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Name="SomeLabel" Content="Hover over me" 
        Background="LightGreen" />
</Grid>
```

When trying to affect one UI element when something happens to another UI element, try to remember this:

> Add the `DataTrigger` to the UI element that is going to change itself in response to the change of another UI element... you will most likely run into problems doing it the other way around.